# Creating a js rangeslider in drupal 8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal, rangeslider

I am working on a Drupal website. The basic setup is that users can make pages/modules, in which one can write html to be rendered by some setups in Drupal, by some predefined css. If I for example want to make a table with a class "someclass", I would type

```
<table class="someclass>
  ...
</table>
```

and save the module. I want to make a slider which users can use to select some value (typically between 1 and 100), and for this I want to use [js-rangeslider](https://rangeslider.js.org/). I am implementing this by adding the code and css from rangeslider.js to the theme of the project, and tells drupal to use it in a yaml file as follows

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/rangeslider.css: {}
  js:
    js/rangeslider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Now I want to make a rangeslider. For this, I have tried the following:

```
<input type="range" class="rangeslider">
```

This doesn't seem to do anything, so I checked up on the [js-rangeslider page](https://rangeslider.js.org/). Here they suggest using jquery to make the element, which makes a lot of sense when using drupal. So I made a script

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myproject = {
    attach: function (context, setting) {
      $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider();   
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

but this doesn't change anything. I still just get a standard range input element. By the way, the jquery does catch the input element, since I've tried console.logging.

I'm hoping I'm just being stupid here, but I have not been able to find a solution anyway. Thanks in advance, Richard.

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to refer you to my module that provides integration with both Drupal's form API and Webform: https://www.drupal.org/project/range_slider

It has a stable release compatible with both Drupal 8 and upcoming 9.

Hope this helps. For any questions I'd be happy to help out in the issue queue of the project: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/range_slider?status=All&categories=All